# How to prove that the return criteria for adding an investment A to an existing portfolio can be represented using Sharpe Ratio Approach

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory

How can I prove that the return criteria for adding an investment A to an existing portfolio can be represented as the below inequality using the Sharpe Ratio Approach for risk adjusted returns as applied to portfolio decision making?[image]

Comment: The Sharpe Ratio condition for the new portfolio (with A) to be better than the old (without A) is $SR_p^{new} \ge SR_p^{old}$. From this we should be able to derive the above. The only probem is that I don't know what $\alpha$ is, how is it defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Denote the old Sharpe ratio by $SR_p^{old}$, and the new one by $SR_p^{new}$. Buy the new asset (i.e., go from old to new) if and only if $SR_p^{new} \ge SR_p^{old}$. let $R_p^{old}$ be the return to the old portfolio and note that the return to the cash benchmark is zero. The differential return, $d^{old}$, is therefore simply $R^{old}$ and the standard deviation is $\sigma_{d^{old}}$. The ratio of $d^{old}$ to $\sigma_{d^{old}}$ then gives us our existing (old) Sharpe ratio.

Suppose that the prospective new portfolio consists of the new asset $A$ and the existing portfolio, in relative proportions $a$ and $1-a$. The expected return on the new portfolio is $R_p^{new} = aR_A + (1 - a)R_p^{old}$, which is also the expected differential for the new portfolio, $d^{new}$.

We should make the investment if
$$ SR^{new}=d^{new}/\sigma_{R_p^{new}} \ge d^{old}/\sigma_{R_p^{old}}$$

Which when substituted and re-arranged, becomes
$$ R_A \ge R_p^{old} + [\sigma_{R_p^{new}} / \sigma_{R_p^{old}} - 1]R_p^{old}/a $$

This answer is found on page 146, Chapter 7, of Dowd, K. (1998). Beyond value at risk: The New Science of Risk Management. Hoboken, NJ: John Wiley & Sons Inc